# Não consigo fazer login com cURL em PHP. a URL não muda

Tags: php, html, formulário, libcurl, login

Estou tentando fazer login em um sistema utilizando cURL. Mas não estou conseguindo logar, acredito que o problema seja o redirecionamento.

Tenho um site (meusite.com.br) que tem um formulário. esse formulário chama a página envio.php . Nessa página eu tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php
//pega os inputs através do furmulário vindo do método POST.
$login  = $_POST['login'];
$senha  = $_POST['senha'];

$ch = curl_init();
$data['login']  = $login;
$data['senha']  = $senha;
$data['submit'] = 'true';
$dataall = http_build_query($data);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sistemaweb/login.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataall);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sistemaweb/dashboard.php');
$a = curl_exec($ch);

echo $a;

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

o problema ocorre quando ele chama a página. ele jogar para o url meusite.com.br/dashboard.php em vez de sistemaweb/dashboard.php

a url não sai do meu domínio. já tentei de diversas formas mas não tive êxito.
até tentei um header location mas parece que ele perce a sessão.

Será que está faltando mais algum parâmetro no processo do CURL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a única possibilidade disso ocorrer é porque o `sistemaweb/dashboard.php` está usando um redirecionamento via Javascript ou o `<meta>`.

Nessa situação, o `sistemaweb/dashboard.php` retorna um `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/dashboard" />`, ou algo similar. Como você está usando o `echo $a`, você acaba por dar print nesse HTML/JS, assim a resposta redireciona o usuário.

Experimente dar um `echo htmlentities($a);` e veja se o comportamento persiste.